# Angular ui-router animating child state changes but not grandchild

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I have an angular app with a main abstract view and nested child views. One of the children of the main view is also abstract with child views of its own.

When I change child states of the main parent, animations work fine but when I change states of the grandchildren there are no animations.

When looking at developers tools I see that the ng-enter and ng-leave classes are added when the children states change but not when the grandchildren change.

Here is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/aYoX7H/) demonstrating the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how your CSS rules are written, you're grabbing ui-view with an attribute selector for `.ng-enter` and `ng-leave`, but declaring the ui view directive both as an element and as an attribute in your html. so you should do something more like this:

```
ui-view.ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-enter { // animation }
```

Here is a working fork of your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bL722pGvBz4xzQnrrz6B?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I was using ui-view as both an attribute and an element, I never noticed. With that information I realized I could make the css changes you suggested or just change my ui-view declaration to attributes so it matches my css and everything is good. Thanks again!